# PHP check if array of arrays has searching value of key in atleast one of them

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array contains data about games per day:

```
"days" => [
    "2019-07-31" => [
        "3" => [
            'id' => 3,
            'type' => normal,
            'teams' => [
                'teamA', 'teamB',
            ],
            'winnerTeam' => 'teamB',
        ],
        "4" => [
            'id' => 4,
            'type' => ranked,
            'teams' => [
                'teamC', 'teamD',
            ],
            'winnerTeam' => 'teamC',
        ],
    ],
    "2019-07-30" => [
        "1" => [
            'id' => 1,
            'type' => normal,
            'teams' => [
                'teamA', 'teamC',
            ],
            'winnerTeam' => 'teamA',
        ],
        "2" => [
            'id' => 2,
            'type' => normal,
            'teams' => [
                'teamB', 'teamD',
            ],
            'winnerTeam' => 'teamC',
        ],
    ],
];
```

I would like to get data about all ranked games, but before i would like to check if any ranked game happen during these days. Does someone knows more elegant method than foreach of foreach everything? So my goal is to check before getting data if any `game['type'] === 'ranked'`

Comment: I mean you can json_encode it and search the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array-column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [array-count-values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to achieve that.

For each day get all the type using `array_column` and then count it and return if the type "ranked" is set in the return array.

Consider the following:

```
foreach($arr["days"] as $day => $a) {
    $aaa = array_count_values(array_column($a, "type"));
    if (isset($aaa['ranked'])) 
        echo "Found in $day \n";
}
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/l3mDb)